# how can i stop a thread on a usercontrol when the form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, user-controls

I have a user control with the following code in it:

```
private Thread updateProgress;
private void FileUploadingScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    updateProgress = new Thread(UpdateProgressBar);
    updateProgress.Start();
}
private bool run = true;
private void UpdateProgressBar()
{
    while (run)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        if(run)
        {
           progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
           {
               if (progressBar1.Value >= 100)
               {
                    progressBar1.Value = 1;
                    progressBar1.Step = 1;
               }
               progressBar1.PerformStep();
           }));
        }
    }
}

public void StopProgressBar()
{
    run = false;
}
```

on the parent form I have :

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    userControl.StopProgressBar();
}
```

when I close the form by clicking the X I'm getting the following error on the `progressBar1.Invoke` line.

> `Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.`

I thought setting run to false in the `form_closing` event would stop this from happening. How can I fix this?  My main goal is to have a progressbar that keeps moving to show that something is happening still. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The error would lead me to believe the thread is already being stopped. What it sounds like is your entire logic of the sleep and checking if it should run is flawed.  Can't you just do updateProgress.Stop() within StopProgressBar?

Comment: @Ramhound - updateProgress doesn't have a stop method. Also I don't think that the thread is being stopped, I think that the form is being closed and along with it the progressBar is being destroyed before the thread stops running.  Is there a better way to have a thread run indefinitely?

Comment: There is `updateProgress.Abort()`, though.

Comment: @MPelletier - I was hoping for something a nicer than that but I guess it is worth a try since nothing else seems to work.

Comment: I'm working on a nicer solution right now, please stand by :)

Comment: using the Abort() method worked. if someone wants to make that an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: Yeah, tried a retro-fit/hack to VS2005 (what I'm stuck with at work) and can't get quite the same behaviour. Will try again from home with VS2008.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  I think it is just a weird race condition.  Abort is good enough for when the form is closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
public void StopProgressBar()
{
    updateProgress.Abort();
}
```

I think it's a valid approach. The application will keep running because there's a thread still active. Aborting that thread shuts it all down.

However, calling this manually every time from outside the UserControl is tedious. You're better off making your user control self-managing and *clean up after itself*.

As per this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167602/how-do-i-add-dispose-functionality-to-a-c-usercontrol), changing the control's Dispose method in Designer.cs is safe, VS should respect these changes and not overwrite them.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    //Special handling of started thread
    if (disposing && updateProgress.IsAlive)
    {
        updateProgress.Abort();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

With this, your parent form does not have to call StopProgressBar explicitly.

Comment: yeah. I guess it doesn't matter if the abort puts in a bad state since it is closing any ways.  I'm using my original StopProgressBar() for normal situations, and this one for when the form closes.  Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it bother you to see the progress bar running in the editor? Or is there a way to turn it off? I didn't try anything for that.

Comment: I'll probably end up overriding dispose as it is a nicer solution.

Comment: @scott See the link to the discussion I put in the answer. You can't override a method from the same class or the other part of a partial class.

Comment: @scott Regarding "running in the editor", I just built myself a small project with your code above. Adding the custom control to a form in the designer, I could see, in design mode, the progress bar filling up and resetting to zero, over and over.

Comment: that is interesting. I don't see that in my editor.  Yes that would bother me. I'm using vs2010 not sure it that is the reason for the different behavior or not.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public void StopProgressBar()
{
    run = false;
    updateProgress.Join();
}
```

The problem is that you're assuming that as soon as you set 'run' to false, the thread is going to stop. What's happening is that Windows continues disposing the window while your thread is still being executed. What this solution does is block until the thread completes execution.

Comment: the application freezes right after I click the X. when I do this.

Comment: What exactly is progressBar1? It would seem to me that your Invoke never returns

Comment: it's a winforms progressbar control.  calling StopProgressBar works fine when I call it normally.  just not from the Form_Closing event. So I'm not sure why it would hang in that situation like it does.

Comment: FYI, the likely reason why this does not work is that StopProgressBar() is called from the UI thread. When you call updateProgress.Join(), the UI thread freezes. In turn, that causes the updateProgress thread to hang forever.