# How to manage disposable object in a WinForms UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, dispose

I'm trying to figure out if I can manage a disposable resource in a `UserControl`.  I have worked around it by managing it in the parent form, but it seems like something that should be possible.

The problem I'm perceiving is I can't override Dispose because `UserControl` implements it but it is not virtual.

Is there any way to work around this without delegating logic to the parent form?

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl {
  MyContext context;
  public void Add(Widget widget) {
    if(this.context== null)
      this.context= new MyContext();
    context.Add(objectToAdd);
  }
  public void Save() {
    if(context!= null)
      context.Save();
  }
  // --> I'd like to override Dispose() so I can call context.Dispose()
  //     but I can't because UserControl implements it and it is not virtual
}
```

Comment: after getting the answer i'll understand if this gets closed for duplicate.. I think I won't delete it because my initial google searches didn't find anything (maybe this will help?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such a case I move the generated Dispose method to the main file and extend it. Visual Studio respects this.

An other approach would be using a partial method (C# 3.0).

Link Here : [How do I add Dispose functionality to a C# UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167602/how-do-i-add-dispose-functionality-to-a-c-sharp-usercontrol)