# no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, dispose

I checked through possible duplicate but cannot find the answer

I have a interface and in the interface there is 2 methods

```
void trigger(IOrderBookDisplay orderbook);
void Dispose(bool disposing);
```

I implemented it implicitly in UserControl1.CS and I got this error

UserControl1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

I deleted the

```
void Dispose(bool disposing);
```

away and I tried UserControl1:IControl,IDisposable and I got the same error

Comment: Members of interface are not virtual. You should not use `override` when implementing them

Comment: The override void Dispose is in UserControl1.Designer.cs. I did not write this code. It was generated. So is it safe to change the override?

Comment: And you didn't modify generated code, e.g. by adding boolean parameter?

Comment: No, I did not change anything in the generated code

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167602/how-do-i-add-dispose-functionality-to-a-c-sharp-usercontrol but in the meantime add the code from the generated file, plus the exact code of the Dispose method that you implemented so we can see what might be going on.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. Don't ask me how, but when I moved my code from the form's `Load` event into the form's constructor, it went away.